# How to select all checkbox inside a gridview?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview, gridview

I want to Check the checkboxes inside a ListView which is Placed inside a Gridview.
The Gridview is having many rows and Each row is having a List view with associated recrods.
Each row contains a CheckBox called select all. I want to check the checkboxes of the child ListView control which accompanies that particular Row.

I have a Server side code from which Im able to do this. but its taking too much time.. ie almost around 1-2 mins to select records if there are more than 1000 records. I want this to be done using a Javascript. how can i achieve this.

[image]

This is the image representing the GridView and ListView.
GridView is Groups and Contacts is the ListView
When i select the "SelectAll" button in the GridView the Appropriate contacts should be selected.

How can I achieve this using Javascript.

This is the code of the grid view

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewGroups" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"                                      
                                onrowdatabound="GridViewGroups_RowDataBound" Width="100%" 
                                BorderColor="Silver" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                                onselectedindexchanged="GridViewGroups_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                                meta:resourcekey="GridViewGroupsResource1" >
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Groups" 
                                    meta:resourcekey="TemplateFieldResource1" HeaderStyle-CssClass="tSubHead">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div align="left" >
                                     <asp:Panel ID="PanelContainer" runat="server" Width="100%" 
                                                meta:resourcekey="PanelContainerResource1" >

                                    <asp:Panel ID="PanelHeaderList" runat="server"   
                                             meta:resourcekey="PanelHeaderListResource1" CssClass="tSubHead2" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="../micons/IC_Plus.png" CssClass="tImage" 
                                            AlternateText="Expand or Collapse" meta:resourcekey="Image1Resource1"/>
                                    <asp:Label ID="LabelGrpName_sm" runat="server" 
                                            Text='<%# string.Format("{0} ({1})", Eval("Grp_Name"),Eval("CountNo")) %>' 
                                            meta:resourcekey="LabelGrpName_smResource1" />
                                     </asp:Panel>
                                    <div style="float:left;width:200px;" >  
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfGrpID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Grp_ID") %>' />     
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxSelect" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" class='<%#Eval("Grp_ID") %>'
                                            OnCheckedChanged="GroupCheckChanged" 
                                            meta:resourcekey="CheckBoxSelectResource1"  />            
                                  <b>  <asp:Label ID="Grp_NameLabel" runat="server" 
                                            Text="Select All" 
                                            meta:resourcekey="Grp_NameLabelResource1" />
                                            </b>

                                    </div>

                                  <br />
                                    <p>
                                    <asp:Panel ID="PanelGroupsItem" runat="server" Width="100%" 
                                            meta:resourcekey="PanelGroupsItemResource1" >
                                    <asp:Panel ID="MyGroups" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="300px" 
                                            Width="100%" Visible='<%# GetFlag(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Grp_ID"))) %>' 
                                            meta:resourcekey="MyGroupsResource1">

                                        <asp:ListView ID="ListViewContactsInGrp" runat="server"  onitemdatabound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" >
                                        <LayoutTemplate>
                                            <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="width:100%;">
                                                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                                                    <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                                                        <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="width:100%;">
                                                            <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="">
                                                                <th id="Th1" runat="server" colspan="2" class="tSubHead2">
                                                                    Contacts</th>                                
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
                                                    <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </LayoutTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                         <tr style="">
                                                <td class="tListViewAlignment" style="width:10px">
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFlag" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="chkFlagResource1" class='<%#Eval("grp_id") %>' />
                                                </td>                
                                                <td class="tListViewAlignment"><asp:Label ID="LabelContacts" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cont_name") %>' 
                                                        meta:resourcekey="LabelContactsResource1"></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfGSM" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("cont_gsm") %>' />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                        </asp:ListView>


                                       </asp:Panel>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                      </p>
                                    <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender1" runat="server"
                                                Collapsed="True"
                                                TargetControlID="PanelGroupsItem"
                                                CollapseControlID="PanelHeaderList"
                                                ExpandControlID="PanelHeaderList"
                                                ImageControlID="Image1"
                                                ExpandedImage="~/micons/IC_minus.png"
                                                CollapsedImage="~/micons/IC_Plus.png"
                                                SuppressPostBack="True" Enabled="True">
                                    </asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                    </div>


                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle BorderColor="Silver" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="Silver" />
                            <RowStyle BorderColor="Silver" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
function SelectCheckboxes(toCheck){
    $("#GridViewGroups input."+toCheck+":checkbox").each(function () {
        this.attr("checked", "checked");
    });
}
```

and you call it like this:

```
OnClick(SelectCheckboxes("class_to_check");)
```

Comment: Im not that much into Jquery. Can you tell me where and all i need to send the ID of the controls??

Comment: @smilu, how is the make up of the gridvieuw? does it got an id or not? And you need to add an class to the checkboxes with the names for wich you select al (are you still following me?). and the you make on onclick event wich will execute the function that i post ( i will edited it now)

Comment: ohhk i'll try it. Gridview is having an ID. All are server controls. Ill try the below one and tell you.

Comment: @smilu The id selecter works with an #. so then instead of gridvieuw whill stand there #idofgridvieuw

Comment: I added all this. but im getting an Jscript error when trying to check the Select All checkbox

Comment: @smilu What is the error that you get? and can you edit your question with some html of the page (how are the ellements made up, id's, classes that sort stsuff)...

Comment: You can check the code. Its giving me error saying the property is invalid.

Comment: @smilu, I've updated the answer. There was indeed an error in my code. I've fixed it, an then it should work. But an another question, where in your code are the checkboxes? or if they are generated when the user loads the page, can you post some of the generated output (where the checkboxes are....

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with jQuery.

```
$("#gridviewID input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
   $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Or if all your checkboxes have the same class

```
$(".checkboxClass").prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have given a name to each checkbox of contact list as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="contacts" id="contact_id" />
```

For the main checkbox which selects all checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="contact_id" onclick="checkAll(this.id)" />
```

You can use following javascript function:

```
 function checkAll(chkid) 
    {
        var chk = document.getElementById(chkid);

        var allchk = document.getElementsByName("contacts");
        for (var i = 0; i < allchk.length; i++) {
            allchk[i].checked = chk.checked;
        }
    }
```

Using this, when you select the "select all" checkbox it will select all the chekboxes named as "contacts"  and it will remove the selected checkbox if "select all" is unselected.